# Path.Combine() C#

Tags: c#, listbox

So on my previous question (C# Only File NAMES in ListBox) I asked how to show only the file names.I got that to work. Then I encountered another problem: I could not load whats in the directory because there is no way to. A user told me

> "
>   You either need to use a Dictionary datasource for your ListBox (with the key being the file name and the value being that path) See this answer for an idea of what I mean. Or you need to rebuild the path in your
>   IndexChange function (using Path.Combine() )
>   "

And me being me, I had no clue what he meant. So I came back for more help. I have not put any code as I don't know how to.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: See if this makes it clearer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netstandard-1.6#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String___

Comment: What research did you do about `Path.Combine()`? What did you understand of it? What is not clear to you?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am not sure how to use it. The user I refrenced linked to me a page about dictionarys (related?) and I read throught, not understanding that either. I have googled `Path.Combine()` and came up close to empty, and anything I saw just confused me more.

Comment: Also it is a listbox where users can add their own items

Comment: Did you read the link shared by Jon Skeet. I saw the answer of your previous question. Did that answer work for you? You need to debug the code of the answer and try to understand what is happening there.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, I read it, but sadly it did not work for me. I didn't know how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string folder = @"C:/Aatrox";    

private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var fileName = (string)ListBox1.SelectedItem;       
     textEditorControl1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Paht.Combine(folder, fileName));
}

private void FlatButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();

        string[] txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
        string[] luafiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.lua");

        foreach (var item in txtfiles)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(item));
        }

        foreach (var item in luafiles)
        {
           ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(item));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a `List` of file names from a certain directory. You want to use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to get each file in the directory. `Path.Combine` only combines a directories path, for modularity and use on other PC's mainly, such as `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Hello")`.